# Excel VBA - Powerpoint Reference not found

Tags: excel, vba, reference, powerpoint

I have a strange issue with my office package. I made an automation from Excel to Powerpoint and it works nice.

But then I switched my place in office (when I took my PC with me).

Since I switched my place the makro didn't work anymore, it says *library not found*, but the library is referenced in the VBA settings.

I have already re-installed Office but its still the same issue..

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmaOy.png)

[Reference Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ7yn.png)

Comment: Start Excel, let it create a new blank workbook, then try adding the same set of references to the new VBA project.  Does it allow you to do this?

Comment: Yes that works normally ? Strange, do i have to recreate the whole Workbook?

Comment: Sorry yes it allowes to add the reference but its also throw the same error on Set PPApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")

Comment: Try running a repair on Office (go to Control Panel | Programs & Features, select Microsoft Office on the list, then use the options at the top of the dialog box to start a repair.)